# Is it acceptable to ask questions that have content from multiple subjects?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I want to ask a question on the '*Mythology and Folklore*' site, pertaining to world ending entities in **mythology**.

In the description I am including the inspiration for the question, which is the lore of the **science fiction** world of '*Warhammer 40k*'.

Is this an acceptable format?

Comment: Could you please [edit] this with more details on what your question would be about?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Did you mean, mention what my question would be ?

Comment: You don't have to quote the question verbatim, although if you want to do that, it would certainly help. But it would be nice to know whether this is primarily a question about real-world mythology, with a brief allusion to Warhammer 40k, or primarily a question about Warhammer 40k.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mythology site [does not accept questions from fictional works](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) such as Warhammer 40K.

> What qualifies as a "myth"?
>
> - Myths that exist solely within a fictional work (e.g., Star Wars, Game of Thrones) are off-topic, though you may be able to ask about them on another site such as SciFi.SE

So I'd avoid mentioning that. If you restricted yourself to myths such as Ragnarok from traditional Norse mythology you'd be on firmer ground.

Comment: And, as the help center says, if you want to ask about Warhammer 40k and not about real-world mythology, we would be very happy to talk about it on [scifi.se]. You might also try [rpg.se], but I'm less aware of their on-/off-topic rules so double-check the help center first.